# Add extra targets to buildin builders

Tags: scons

I need some extra files (p.ex. memory mapping) from the linker thus I've modified the flags accordingly: `myenv.Append(LINKFLAGS=...)`

How could I get these additional `.map` files cleaned up with `scons -c`?

I know there are `Emitters` to add targets. Is it possible to extend a buildin builder of `myenv`?

What is an appropriate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do it. Scons provides a variable `PROGEMITTER` which is documented as 'TODO'.

```
def prog_emitter(target, source, env):
    # assume target is a list!
    # exchange extension of target file with .map
    target.append(os.path.splitext(target[0].get_path())[0] + '.map')
    return target, source

myenv.Append(PROGEMITTER=prog_emitter)
```

For other builders you could use [`add_emitter`](http://www.scons.org/doc/latest/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Builder.BuilderBase-class.html#add_emitter). You'll find all loaded builders in `myenv['BUILDERS']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the name of the file is going to be, then you list it as a [side effect](http://www.scons.org/wiki/SConsMethods/SideEffect) and set it to be [cleaned](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.1.0/HTML/scons-user/x3159.html).

```
myenv.Append(LINKFLAGS=...)
lib = myenv.SharedLibrary(source)
map = SideEffect('file.map', lib)
Clean(lib, map)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why exactly you think that SideEffect should be used here? Why not simply Clean(lib, 'file.map')?

Comment: I don't want to add a `SideEffect()` or something else to each `Program()`. There sould be an easier way: modifying the builder...

Comment: @dirkbaechle I usually use the SideEffect function because it returns me a node which I can include in a list of targets to be installed.  I believe that you are right that it is not necessary if you are only interested in cleaning it up.

Comment: @Knut, you could easily include the call to Clean in a wrapper around the Program() builder.

Comment: @Kenneth Please keep in mind that marking a Node as SideEffect, effectively prevents the associated Builder from getting executed in parallel. You're serializing your single calls for the same Builder, as long as the same SideEffect file is affected. This is the actual intention of the SideEffect() method...so you may want to use it rarely, and prefer Clean() in general. You can always create proper nodes to pass around with the File() and Dir() methods, if required at all.

Comment: @dirkbaechle if I do not list a file as a side effect of another build action, and then I install that file somewhere, how does SCons know it has to execute the build action prior to installing the file?

Comment: If your Builder is written correctly, its Emitter will add the file to the list of created targets. This is then enough information for SCons to draw the connection...it sees that the additional file has a "Builder" attached to it, so when traversing the build tree and hitting upon the "install" target it ensures that the checksums/timestamps of all children are up-to-date. Otherwise a rebuild is triggered...for more infos about this, feel free to ask on scons-users@scons.org .

Comment: @dirkbaechle I believe the OP was asking how to do this with a builtin builder (Program, Library, etc...), not a custom builder.

Comment: Well, you didn't really answer his question (Is it possible to extend a buildin builder) then, right? I mean, you can either say "this is only about builtin builders" or "workarounds and additional paths are acceptable" for this question. Which do you pick? Depending on your choice I can then comment further...